# Am I partitioning my tables in the wrong way on BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I recently joined a new company where BigQuery is the main database. I saw that most of their tables were partitioned by their ingestion_date (1 ingestion per day).

I am in charge to write a custom query and I need to use one of those partitioned tables in my query, I only need to rows that were ingested yesterday where yesterday is `DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)`

But my query on my partition by ingestion_date (column `prc_tms_process`) which is a timestamp of when the data was added on the table. But when I query that table with a partition on `prc_tms_process`, the cost of the query is almost 50% more expensive that the one without partition. I thought partitioning tables will let me only query relevant subsets of data (by bay) which will reduce query cost.

`SELECT paid_fees, total_fees  FROM table_a WHERE DATE(prc_tms_process) = "2023-04-25"` --> **70 GB**

`SELECT paid_fees, total_fees  FROM table_a` --> **51 GB**

After reading some documentation online, seems there is a _PARTITIONDATE column that may be what I am looking for:

```
SELECT 
  _PARTITIONDATE AS pd
FROM 
  dataset.table_a
```

I am getting: `Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONDATE at [2:3]`. Seems that column was probably overridden by our custom `prc_tms_process` column?

So I am a bit confused, are we doing partitioning wrong for this table `table_a`, that column `prc_tms_process` is actually inside the table, is this normal, shouldn't the partition be a metadata and not a column within the table? 90% of our use cases we only need to query either today or yesterday so `_PARTITIONDATE` seems to be the best solution to reduce our costs.

Comment: Are you dealing with timestamps or dates? In particular Is the partition on a timestamp column or date column? Approx how many rows are added each time?

Answer (score 0):

To query an ingestion-time partitioned table, you can use the pseudo column `_PARTITIONTIME`, which contains the timestamp for when the data was loaded to BigQuery. For example,

```sql
SELECT paid_fees, total_fees
FROM table_a
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2023-04-25)
```